# How to refer to a group of people living in present when writing about the future/past

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a paper exploring how a particular profession would change in the future. I am wondering how I would refer back to the people in present times who are practicing that profession.

Example: 
When talking about future computer scientists, refer back to computer scientists living in the present day.

Simply using "modern day computer scientists", or "present day computer scientists" may be confusing, is there a single word i can use to say this?

Example of usage:
In order to determine the short term goals of [requested word] computer scientists, we can examine how the profession could change over time.

Comment: You might get some writing advice over at Writers.SE (that's what they do there)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We **latterday** computer scientists who are living in the year 2150, at least some of us, refer to computer scientists who lived in the 21st century as **antiquated** computer scientists, while others call them **pioneers**.

Comment: Latterday is super helpful for the inverse of this question, thanks! I will go with pioneers for now.

Answer (score -1):

The appropriate word in your context should be ***contemporary*** (implying "of present times").

> In order to determine the short term goals of ***contemporary***
>   computer scientists, we can examine how the profession could change
>   over time.

ODO:

> **[contemporary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contemporary)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>   **2** Belonging to or occurring in the present.
>
> ‘the tension and complexities of our contemporary society’
>
> ‘Readers will not get a strong sense of the historical processes that
>   led each of these four groups to the structure and belief system
>   present in the contemporary world.’

Online example from [Rhymezone](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?loc=olthes1&typeofrhyme=wke&Word=contemporary):

> Contemporary interpreters are not bound by how people in
>   1868 would have applied these words and meanings to issues such as
>   racial...
>   —[Originalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Originalism)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think that helps. The OP specifically rejected "modern day" and "present day" as being potentially confusing, "contemporary" is, mainly, another way of saying the same thing. You can use "contemporary" when talking about the past but you have anchor it carefully. For instance "James Cook's use of a Harrison chronometer meant that he employed the cutting edge of contemporary timepiece technology"

Comment: I agree that contemporary is extremely ambiguous. I don't see why "present day" would be; I would always assume it refers to "now" rather than being contemporary with the past or future being discussed.